# How can use python to arrange objects in a circular pattern?

Tags: python, geometry, blender

I am using python in blender and I would like to know how to use python to take a number of objects in a scene and arrange them in a circular pattern, evenly spaced, with a set minimum amount of space in between each object.

I was thinking of having python read the number of objects in the scene and create a circle with that number of vertices.  Then move each object to its own vertice on the circle while making sure the circle edges are at least the minimum length.

Is this over complicating things?  What other method should I use?

Comment: There are two questions here. One is python specific, and one is a general algorithmic question. Which one are you asking? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I recall a question similar to this one, albeit using PIL instead of blender: [arrange images on canvas in a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383112/python-arrange-images-on-canvas-in-a-circle)

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because I honestly don't even know where to look.  I don't understand about there being two different questions but if you ignore the second paragraph maybe it will make more sense.  I am asking how to use python to arrange objects in a circular pattern where the radius of the "circle" is dependent upon the number of objects and the objects being a set minimum distance apart from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @joel that this is really two separate questions.

As shown here - [Python Tool-tip](http://wiki.blender.org/uploads/e/ec/1_2_ToolTipMenu.png) hovering over most UI element give you the python data access for the property/operator. If you don't care about what the object type is then just find the object operator used to create one of the primitive objects and use that.

For more advanced object generation I would check out - [Blender Python API - Cookbook](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook)

Once you know how to create objects, then you can create x number of objects and offset them based on an algorithm of your choice. A quick search is all that is needed if you do not want to develop your own code - [Distribute-points-on-a-circle-as-evenly-as-possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479736/distribute-points-on-a-circle-as-evenly-as-possible)